# Error while starting jetty server (version 9.2.15 ) to run on SSL

Tags: web-applications, struts2, jetty-9

I want to rum my web application on jetty server with ssl configuration. On running command java -jar start.jar following exceptions are generating -

> *> *2016-05-05 18:26:50.279:INFO::main: Logging initialized @487ms 2016-05-05 18:26:50.367:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance
>   of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this
>   is not recommended.  See documentation at
>   http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
>   2016-05-05 18:26:50.639:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
>   2016-05-05 18:26:50.653:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main:
>   Deployment monitor [file:/usr/java/jetty/jetty9.2.15/webapps/] at
>   interval 1 2016-05-05
>   18:26:51.045:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp87150572-15: 
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
>   org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-05-05
>   18:26:51.045:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp87150572-15: Unexpected
>   thread death:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3@4490bc23 in
>   qtp87150572{STARTED,10<=10<=200,i=7,q=0} 2016-05-05
>   18:26:51.046:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:qtp87150572-14: 
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
>   org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:974)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:688)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:824)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:549)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)**

**My application loads on web page but after login it return below error on webpage-**

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   

    The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    ServletException including path '/Tiles/baseLayout.jsp'.
    ServletException including path '/Tiles/baseLayout.jsp'.
...
```

Need your help since I have tried a lot of configurations but failed ..

Comment: Add the struts2-tiles-plugin

Comment: *I have tried a lot of configurations...* where?

Comment: In jetty specifically. There were conflicts of jars since my app used different version of jars. So i tried replacing the jars in jetty with jars used in app.  I have used different versions of jetty. Tried configuring jetty-runner to use SSL but failed. Then tried configuring SSL in start.ini file and run jetty with start.jar but it is not working. My webapp works fine on http on jetty9.0.3, but i want to deploy the app on https.

Comment: @AndreaLigios struts2-tiles-pligin-2.1.6.jar is present in jetty lib folder.

Comment: Which struts version are you using ?

Comment: i am using struts2

Comment: Which struts**2** version are you using ?

Comment: Using struts-2.1.6